# Concept for animating many elements in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am in the situation to visualize many seperate elements. With many I mean 15 to 40.

It is to cumbersome to animate every element by hand in XAML. The animatiom is straightforward, all elements are decreased in size or moved into one direction. It's a flow-chart which has to be minimized.

Is there a way to animate these elements, maybe in a programmatically way so I can loop over the elements any apply similiar animation?

Comment: Could you supply an example of a single or two of these animations?

Comment: Why not apply an animation to resize (maybe a Scale transformation) the whole flow-chart, and the elements of the flow-chart should have sizes and positions relative to it.

Comment: @Jogy This sounds interesting, but how do you apply an animation to the whole flow-chart, respectively to the whole elements?

Comment: Well, it depends on what the flow-chart is. What are you using? Is it some sort of a WPF control? How are the elements managed?

Comment: @Jogy: Different for now: Images, Polygons, Lines and Ellipses. I also think about custom controls. The elements are just inserted into the Canvas and an double animation is simple applied for every element in a trigger.

Comment: If the elements of flow-chart does not need to be active while minimized, then you can create a VisualBrush from the flow-chart Canvas, paint this VisualBrush to an image and apply animations to the image. See this blog post for an example: http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2007/05/15/wpf-visualbrush-basics/

Comment: @Jogy: This is really nice, but in fact the elements are minimized but still in use. I guess it is possible to put all the elements into a canvas an animate all elements inside?

Comment: Yes, you can create one Storyboard, and then add animations for each element to it. You can do it in code. See the answer for a sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the animations in code and put them in a Storyboard, so that they run syncronously:

```
    <Canvas Name="canvas" Width="200" Height="200">
      <Rectangle Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="20" Stroke="Red" Fill="Orange" Width="30" Height="20" />
      <Ellipse Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="40" Stroke="Blue" Fill="Green" Width="40" Height="30" />
    </Canvas>
    <Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="Click" Click="Button_Click" />



private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();

  Duration dur = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));

  foreach (FrameworkElement child in canvas.Children) 
  {
    DoubleAnimation leftAnim = new DoubleAnimation(Canvas.GetLeft(child) / 2, dur);
    DoubleAnimation topAnim = new DoubleAnimation(Canvas.GetTop(child) / 2, dur);
    DoubleAnimation widthAnim = new DoubleAnimation(child.Width / 2, dur);
    DoubleAnimation heightAnim = new DoubleAnimation(child.Height / 2, dur);

    sb.Children.Add(leftAnim);
    sb.Children.Add(topAnim);
    sb.Children.Add(widthAnim);
    sb.Children.Add(heightAnim);

    Storyboard.SetTarget(leftAnim, child);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(topAnim, child);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(widthAnim, child);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(heightAnim, child);

    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(leftAnim, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Left)"));
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(topAnim, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Top)"));
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(widthAnim, new PropertyPath("Width"));
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(heightAnim, new PropertyPath("Height"));
  }

  sb.Begin();
}
```